# Best practice to filter case class object attributes

Tags: scala

Say I have case classes like

```
case class Person(name:String, id: Int)
case class Country(name:String, population: Long, continent:String)
case class City(name: String, place: Country)
```

Now I would like to make a search operation using this piece of generic code

```
def search[T](searchIn: Seq[T], seachFor:String) : Seq[T] = {
     val result = searchIn flatMap {
       case p: Person if(p.name.contains(searchFor)) => Some(p)
       case c: Country if(c.continent.contains(searchFor)) => Some(c)
       case c: City if(c.name.contains(serachFor)) => Some(c)
       case _ => None 
   }
  result.map(_.asInstanceOf[T])
}
```

Challenge here is I might need to make search in few more attributes for existing case classes or I need to have more cases classes.

I don't feel like the above code is generic as I need to know which object it is, search in it and convert it back.

What is best approach to this type of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would introduce a `trait`like:

```
trait Searchable {
  def filter(searchFor:String):Boolean
}
```

Now your case classes look like:

```
case class Person(name:String, id: Int) extends Searchable {
  def filter(searchFor:String):Boolean = name.contains(searchFor) 
}
case class Country(name:String, population: Long, continent:String) extends Searchable {
  def filter(searchFor:String):Boolean = continent.contains(searchFor) 
}
case class City(name: String, place: Country) extends Searchable {
  def filter(searchFor:String):Boolean = name.contains(searchFor) 
}
```

And the function is:

```
def search[T <: Searchable](searchIn: Seq[T], searchFor:String) : Seq[T] = 
 searchIn.filter(_.filter(searchFor))
```

Here is a ScalaFiddle if you want to play with that: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/qgFxWZF/2

**Restriction**

As you see with the answer of @ccheneson there is even a more generic solution. So if you want to search in `case classes` you do not have in control - you need something like `Type Classes`.

Comment: `I might need to make search in few more attributes for existing case classes or I need to have more cases classes`. As mentioned please understand this can be problem when I try to use new attributes for my search

Comment: @PuneethReddyV that looks nearly the same - see my edited answer

Comment: @PuneethReddyV For a more general search the trait can have a method `def match(searchString: String): Boolean`. The search then becomes `searchIn.filter(_.match(searchString))`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using type classes:

```
case class Person(name: String, id: Int)
case class Country(name: String, population: Long, continent: String)
case class City(name: String, place: Country)


sealed trait SearchAble[T] {
  def searchContains(p: Seq[T], s: String): Option[T]
}

object SearchAbleImpls {

  implicit object SearchAbleImplPerson extends SearchAble[Person] {
    override def searchContains(p: Seq[Person], s: String): Option[Person] = {
      println("SearchAbleImplPerson to implement")
      None
    }
  }

  implicit object SearchAbleImplCountry extends SearchAble[Country] {
    override def searchContains(p: Seq[Country], s: String): Option[Country] = {
      println("SearchAbleImplCountry to implement")
      None
    }
  }

  implicit object SearchAbleImplCity extends SearchAble[City] {
    override def searchContains(p: Seq[City], s: String): Option[City] = {
      println("SearchAbleImplCity to implement")
      None
    }
  }

}

object Main {

  import SearchAbleImpls._

  def search[T](searchIn: Seq[T], seachFor: String)(implicit ev: SearchAble[T]): Unit = {
    ev.searchContains(searchIn, seachFor)
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val listPerson = Seq(Person("BOB", 2), Person("JOHN", 3))
    search(listPerson, "N")

    val listCountry = Seq(Country("US", 2, "AMERICA"), Country("FR", 3, "EUROPE"))
    search(listCountry, "N")

    val listCity = Seq(City("NY", Country("US", 2, "AMERICA")), City("CA", Country("FR", 3, "EUROPE")))
    search(listCity, "N")

  }
}
```

All you have to do is to implement the search of the specific objects (`Person`, `Country`, `City`). This will allow you to use the attributes you need for the search. Calling `ev.searchContains` will call the search implementation for the right type.